# Why does SvelteKit require to include dependent scss files each time instead requiring them once, globally?

Tags: bootstrap-4, sass, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I'm trying to build a project using SvelteKit and Bootstrap.

After including all Bootstrap related scss files in the `+layout.css` file, I receive an error from my `custom.scss` style file saying:

```
[sass] Undefined mixin.

53 │ ┌         @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
54 │ │             ...
65 │ └         }
   ╵
  src/lib/css/custom.scss 53:9  root stylesheet
```

Here is my `+layout.svelte` file:

```
<script>
    //scss
    import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss'
    import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.scss'
    import '$lib/css/custom.scss'

    //js
    import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle'
</script>

<slot></slot>
```

I've managed to identify the fact that I can get around by importing `bootstrap/scss/mixins` inside my `custom.css` file.

Why do I have to include again the `@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins"` line in my `custom.scss` file in order to make it work, since the file is already included in `bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss` which is included in the `+layout.svelte` file?

P.S. - I have enabled [vitePreprocess](https://github.com/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/blob/main/docs/preprocess.md) for SvelteKit.

I have previously used Laravel Mix which worked as intended. Could someone explain to me why this behaviour in SvelteKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An import in `script` is an isolated inclusion of the styles, they do not "communicate". As `@include` is something that has to happen in the preprocessing, importing the various files separately will not work.

You should be able to create e.g. a `bundle.scss` that internally imports the files, that way they should all be processed together.

Otherwise there is the option to not import in the `<script>` but rather in `<style lang="scss">` using SASS/CSS import mechanisms instead. (There you may need to put everything in a `:global` block to prevent scoping.)